Implications of disabling SignalR MaximumReceiveMessageSize and possible mitigations
What are the implications (e.g. security, performance) of disabling the MaximumReceiveMessageSize for SignalR on the server?
The Microsoft docs state that

Increasing the value might increase the risk of Denial of service (DoS) attacks.

(from here)
Is this risk mitigated at all by using an AuthenticationScheme on the SignalR hub requiring bearer access tokens in the HTTP headers (i.e. does this prevent unauthorized users from performing DoS attacks)?
